# Understanding PWM ports in arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

(new to arduino) what is wrong with the code below, I can see port 9 and 10 blinks at same time, later port 11 blinks.

when I try with port 3, 5, 6 it works fine.
I have problem only with 9,10,11 ports

```
const int col[3] = {9,10,11};

void setup() {
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < 3; thisPin++) {
    pinMode(col[thisPin], OUTPUT); 
  }
}

void loop() {
  refreshScreen();
}  

void refreshScreen() {
  for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    digitalWrite(col[index], HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(col[index], LOW);
  }
}
```

does my arduino has defect or is it PWM ports behave like this!!! ?

Comment: Should be migrated to the Arduino SE.

Answer (score 0):

PWM pins work the same as any other using digitalWrite(). It looks to me like the code should work. Is it possible that you're somehow shorting the outputs of 9 and 10 together? If not, sounds to me like pins 9 and 10 are defective.